# Couldn't find Category without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize3

I got such error after I globalized my app using **globalize3** gem.Before that It worked fine. It is because of that I translated all categories in 3 different languages. And at this moment it can't find that category. Because I am using that category name inside link. So if there is 3 categories then each time it should correspond to that category. But it not.
Here is my code.

*My application layout*

```
 <% @categs1.each do |categ|%>
    <li>  <%= link_to (categ.name), products_path(:category => categ.name)   %> </li>
 <%end%>
```

*My routes file*

```
  root :to => 'home#index'

devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

namespace :products do
  resources :categories do
    resources :products
  end
  resources :products, only: :index
end

match '/:locale' => 'home#index'
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|lv|ru/ do
 resources :products, :manufacturers, :categories, :news, :ActiveAdmin
```

*Products_controller*

```
 @categs1 =  Category.find(:conditions => { :id => [16,21,29,30] })
```

If you need additional code, please ask me. I am stuck here for two days already:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` like following to get your desired result.

In your `ProductsController`:

```
@categs1 =  Category.where({ :id => [16,21,29,30] })
```

or if you'd like to stick to `find` then use this:

```
@categs1 =  Category.find(:all, :conditions => { :id => [16,21,29,30] })
```